existence of a limit implies that a function can be extended to a harmonic function
Theorem
If $u: \mathbb{D'} = \mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic and bounded, then $u$ extends to a function harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$.

In the next proof $\Pi^+$ is the upper half-plane.
Proof: Define a function $U: \Pi^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $U(z)=u\left(e^{2 \pi i z}\right)$. Then $U$ is harmonic, being the composition of a harmonic function and a holomorphic function. Since $\Pi^{+}$is simply connected, there exists $F \in$ $H\left(\Pi^{+}\right)$such that $U=\mathbb{R e}(F)$. Now, although $U(z+1)=U(z)$ we need not have $F(z+1)=F(z)$. But $\mathbb{R e}(F(z+1)-F(z))=U(z+1)-U(z)=0$. and so $F(z+1)-F(z)$ must be an imaginary constant: There exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(z+1)-F(z)=$ ic for all $z \in \Pi^{+}$. Choose a real number $\alpha \neq 0$ so that $c \alpha$ is a multiple of $2 \pi$ (you can take $\alpha=2 \pi / c$ unless $c=0$ ). Let
$$
E(z)=e^{\alpha F(z)}
$$
It follows that $E(z+1)=E(z)$, and so there exists $f \in H\left(\mathbb{D}^{\prime}\right)$ with
$$
E(z)=f\left(e^{2 \pi i z}\right) .
$$
Now the fact that $u$ is bounded shows that $f$ is bounded, so that $f$ has a removable singularity at the origin. The fact that $u$ is bounded also shows that $f$ is bounded away from 0 , so in particular $f(0) \neq 0$. Hence $u$ has a limit at 0 , since $u=\log (|f|) / \alpha$. (Since $f\left(e^{2 \pi i z}\right)=e^{\alpha F(z)}$ it follows that
$$
\left.\log \left(\left|f\left(e^{2 \pi i z}\right)\right|\right)=\alpha \mathbb{R e}(F(z))=\alpha U(z)=\alpha u\left(e^{2 \pi i z}\right) .\right)
$$

Question
Why the fact that $u$ has limit at $0$ implies that $u$ can be extended to a harmonic function $u : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{R}$?
 Edit: 
For clarifying: I want to know why that "$u$ has limit at $0$" implies that the proof is completed and the function $u$ extends to a harmonic function on all $\mathbb{D}$.
 Edit 2: 
We have that $e^{\alpha F(z)} = f(e^{2 \pi i z})$ and this implies
$ \begin{gather*}
            |{e^{\alpha F(z)}| = |f(e^{2 \pi i z})| \iff e^{\alpha \Re\big(F(z)\big)} = |f(e^{2 \pi i z})| \iff e^{\alpha U(z)} = |f(e^{2 \pi i z})| \\
            \iff \alpha U(z) = \ln{|f(e^{2 \pi i z})|} \iff \alpha u(e^{2 \pi i z}) = \ln{|f(e^{2 \pi i z})}|} 
        \end{gather*}
$
and by the fact that the function $g:\Pi^+ \to \mathbb{D}',\, g(z) = e^{2 \pi i z}$ is surjective, we have that upper equality is equivalent to
$$\alpha u(z) = \ln{|f(z)|} \iff e^{\alpha u(z)} = |f(z)|.$$
Now, because $u$ is bounded, it results that $\alpha u$ is bounded, so image of $\alpha u$ can be included in a closed disk (which is also compact) and image of that disk through the function $e^z$ (which is continuous) is also a compact set (which is bounded), so $e^{\alpha u}$ is a bounded function which implies that $f$ is a bounded function. Now, because $e^{\alpha u(z)} \ne 0$ for all $z$ this implies that $|f(z)| > 0$ for all $z$, so $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
